# Adobe Air application maximum window size - how to set?

Tags: apache-flex, air, height, width

I've an Air application, which I want to maximize at the startup. I set the width and height value to 100% but it didn't help me. I've tried to set the percentWidth, percentHeight values to 100 but it didn't work neither.

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   width="100%" height="100%"
```

All the components properties are set to 100% but the application doesn't start in maximum size. How should I set them properly?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WindowedApplication` instance is not the window itself, but it runs inside a native window. So by setting `width="100%"`, you're effectively saying: take up the entire width of the native window. Hence you're not resizing the window itself.

You can access this native window your application is running in through `WindowedApplication`'s [nativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/WindowedApplication.html#nativeWindow) property. This returns an instance of the `NativeWindow` class, which in turn has a [maximize()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#maximize%28%29) function.

So to maximize your application simply do this inside the `WindowedApplication` instance:

```
nativeWindow.maximize();
```